# Azure DevOps Chat options

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I see the option to chat my team members by mouse-over their profile icon, but the chat link launches Skype. Is this the only chat option or can we link it to Slack or another chat engine? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Check Slack Integration extension

NOTE: This extension is pre-installed with Azure DevOps Services and Team Foundation Server 2015 and later.

Slack is a popular team collaboration service that helps teams be more productive by keeping all communications in one place and easily searchable from virtually anywhere. All your messages, your files, and everything from Twitter, Dropbox, Google Docs, Azure DevOps, and more all together. Slack also has fully native apps for iOS and Android to give you the full functionality of Slack wherever you go.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.vss-services-slack